# Браузер в Qt [MinGW]

Tags: qt, mingw, qtwebengine

Всем здравствуйте. В Qt технология для браузера, называется `QtWebEngine`, и он поддерживается только компилятором MSVC. А что делать пользователям Linux'а, ведь там нет Visual Studio. Как в таком случае сделать браузер? Если нет MSVC, остается только MinGW.

Comment: В linux нет mingw. Есть gcc, и поддержка `QtWebEngine`.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо Вам огромное!